# Cassandra: Is there a limit to amount of data that a collection column can hold?

Tags: cassandra, cql

In the below table, what is the maximum size *phone_numbers* column can accommodate ?

1. Like normal columns, is it 2GB ?
2. Is it 64K*64K as mentioned [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html#useCollections__useCollections_unique_1)

```
CREATE TABLE d2.employee (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    doj timestamp,
    name text,
    phone_numbers map<text, text>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collection types in Cassandra are represented as a set of distinct cells in the internal data model: you will have a cell for each key of your phone_numbers column. Therefore they are not normal columns, but a set of columns. You can verify this by executing the following command in cassandra-cli (1001 stands for a valid employee id):

```
use d2;
get employee[1001];
```

The good answer is your point 2.